# Getting variable inputs in powershell from PHP

Tags: php, powershell

I have a PHP webpage where the user inputs the name of the server they want to see stats on. I need to then pass the sever input name from the php webpage to a powershell file where that input will be defined as a variable and used in the powershell coding to accomplish tasks (aka take a snapshot etc.)

PHP so far:

```
< ?php require("automation_lib.php"); ?>
< ?php require("load_page.php") ?>

< ?php $server= $_GET['server'];
// pulling the information from the server input on homepage
$psScriptPath = 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Automation2\connection.ps1';
// telling the path to get the powershell file from
```

(automation.php and load_page.php are where the servers are defined)

I know in my powershell connection.ps1 file I need to use parameters, but unsure how.

Comment: Could write `$server` to a file for powershell to use later on. When you call a powershell script you can append any arguments/parameters to it and it stores them in an array in the $args varible
so if you call the params.ps1 script with "server1" as the parameter:
`params.ps1 "server1"`


In params.ps1 you would have this to retrieve and store the param in another variable:

`$server = $args[0] #0 is the first item of an array`